# How can I extract part of a string with different lengths and insert it into a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I uploaded some data from excel sheet to a table in sql , I would like to use part of the string that I inserted into the column `PPRName` and insert into another table `[Verify]`.

The data in the column when inserted looks like this:

> August 2018  **[ NW: Construction MTP021 - Building and Civil Construction: Masonry NQF 3 ]**

I want to insert this part of the string :

> **NW: Construction MTP021 - Building and Civil Construction: Masonry NQF 3**

into another table `[Verify]` for every PPR Name in the `PPRName` column. The names of the PPRs vary in length but all come in same format.

I would also like to extract the **August 2018** and cast it as a date and insert into my table [Verify].

I am not sure how to use `Charindex` and `Substrings` to achieve this.

i tried this but no data was returned

```
select SUBSTRING([PPR_Caption],charindex('[',[PPR_Caption]),charindex([PPR_Caption],']')) 

FROM [dbo].[PPRS]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to do this? Please do share your attempt? `'August 2018'`, on it's own isn't a date. A date consists of the **day**, month and year. What date are you expected `'August 2018'` to represent?

Comment: Please provide more sample data to assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly use the 2nd `CHARINDEX` and you incorrectly use the `SUBSTRING` commands.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(PPR_Caption, CHARINDEX("[", PPR_Caption) + 1, CHARINDEX("]", PPR_Caption) - CHARINDEX("[", PPR_Caption) - 1)
FROM PPRS
```

`SUBSTRING` uses a start and a lenght, not the start and end point. To get the length use your end point and substract the start point (and correct the 1 position offset with -1).
In your 2nd `CHARINDEX` you switched the string to search in and the string to look for.

Comment: it says 'LOCATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Indeed @Makaziwe, corrected it. It was the MySQL equivalent I tested and forgot to change back.

Comment: it now says 'Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.'

Answer (score 0):

String operations like this are cumbersome in SQL Server.

Try this:

```
select replace(v2.str_rest, ' ]', '') as name, cast(str_start as date) as dte
from (values ('August 2018 [ NW: Construction MTP021 - Building and Civil Construction: Masonry NQF 3 ]')
     ) v(str) cross apply
     (values (stuff(v.str, 1, charindex('[', str) + 1, ''), substring(v.str, 1, charindex('[', str) -1))
     ) v2(str_rest, str_start);
```

SQL Server is pretty good about guessing formats for converting dates, so it will actually convert the date without the day of the month.